# Inactive Fluid flat glitch

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am animating a fluid simulation that's supposed to be used for an animated simulation of 'the floor is Lava', the details are unimportant.
What is important is that to ensure the items that fall into the lava impact I'm using a domain that extends into the room, so I set it to stop filling after a certain point. I also abruptly slow down the speed of the simulation, from 60 to 20 seconds. This is all well and good but when It reaches the key frame point the fluid becomes, well:
Before
[image]

After
[image]

I don't know what's causing it so I need help, is there A a fix to this or B another way to achieve stopping the inflow.
To clarify I stopped it by key framing the 'enabled' modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own answer.
I had an obstacle representing the room the lava will be beneath, when I cut the inflow I moved the obstacle all the way out of the domain, It appears that this is what caused the glitch, and moving it only slightly seems to have worked.